# Minecraft Server Hide Plugins & Commands Help

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do i make it so like my default users cannot see plugins, when they do /help they see the plugins and the command that they cannot use. How do i fix it so they can't see plugins or the plugins commands?

Answer (score 1):

)
The Information you want to alter is stored in a file called help.yml .
You are able to change it with a simple text editor.
Have a look at this link: http://wiki.bukkit.org/Help.yml

ps.: you also should deactivate the /plugins command, as it lists every plugin you've got installed and running.

pps.: the configuration is a little more complicated, as most of the plugins send their own help texts - so, if you enter /economy or sth. economy will answer with it's own help.
So, you should not only change one yml file, but everyone related to the hidden plugins.

Furthermore you should take a look at a permission plugin if you hadn't already.
If you're not working with multiple servers (not talking about different world generated by multiverse) [PEX](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/permissionsex/) is a nice tool to start.

I hope this answered your question ;)